# Python in Neovim, xxx is not a known member of module

Tags: python, lua, neovim

I am trying to setup Neovim to work with Python, I have a simple `main.py` file that when I open inside Neovim I keep getting

`Pyright: "imread" is not a known member of module`

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
```

But when I open the same file in VsCode its working is intended.

My LSP Info is

```
 Language client log: /home/nikola/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log
 Detected filetype:   python
 
 4 client(s) attached to this buffer: 
 
 Client: copilot (id: 1, pid: nil, bufnr: [4])
    filetypes:       
    autostart:       true
    root directory:  /mnt/image-manipulation
    cmd:             node /home/nikola/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/opt/copilot.lua/copilot/index.js
 
 Client: null-ls (id: 2, pid: 5001, bufnr: [4])
    filetypes:       sh, python, luau, lua, java, pgsql, sql, json, markdown, typescriptreact, vue, javascriptreact, javascript, typescript, zsh, NeogitCommitMessage, gitrebase, go, tex, org, text
    autostart:       false
    root directory:  /mnt/image-manipulation
    cmd:             <function>
 
 Client: pylsp (id: 3, pid: nil, bufnr: [4])
    filetypes:       python
    autostart:       true
    root directory:  Running in single file mode.
    cmd:             pylsp
 
 Client: pyright (id: 4, pid: nil, bufnr: [4])
    filetypes:       python
    autostart:       true
    root directory:  Running in single file mode.
    cmd:             pyright-langserver --stdio
 
 Configured servers list: gopls, html, jsonls, tailwindcss, tsserver, pyright, sumneko_lua, pylsp, rust_analyzer
```

And my LSP setup is extensive [but here is a snippet of the python setup](https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/.dotfiles/blob/master/nvim/.config/nvim/lua/nikola/lsp/init.lua#L6)

```
local M = {}

local servers = {
    pylsp = {
        plugins = {
            pylint = { enabled = true, executable = "pylint" },
            pyflakes = { enabled = false },
            pycodestyle = { enabled = false },
            jedi_completion = { fuzzy = true },
            pyls_isort = { enabled = true },
            pylsp_mypy = { enabled = true },
        },
    },
    pyright = {
        analysis = {
            typeCheckingMode = "off",
        },
    },
```

I have no idea what is happening as I am new to the Python ecosystem and there is too much tooling involved, also the Neovim as much as it is great to use, configuring it like this has become a real hassle, I think I have everything I need. This must be a problem with a missing tool or connection between the LSP and something, as it's working fine in other IDE's.

Comment: `cv2` is a c++ package and has a wrapper in Python. So LSP may not be able to know its member functions. I think vscode may have some stub files to make the autocompletion work.

Comment: @jdhao very interesting, haven't thought about that, I think I read about stubs in python but haven't known what they're used for until now. Thanks for the heads up